# Transformer power rating and RMS current?

Tags: power, current, transformer

[image]

V1 is the output (secondary side) of a step down transformer. LTspice shows me this:

```
RMS voltage across V1 = 9.5V
RMS current through V1 = 1.96A
Average power at V1 = 12.36W
```

So what is the correct VA rating of the transformer, and what is the correct current rating of the transformer? How much current should I expect to be able to draw through R2 without damaging the transformer? Can a 18VA transformer, only supply 12W? It is somewhat confusing for me.

```
each diode
     1.4A RMS, 0.5A average, 0.5W average (datasheet limits 1A average)
2N3055
    1.36W average
```

So, diodes are safe, right?

Comment: Each trafo has a specific efficiency. For example, let's say the one you need has 80%. Then, for your maximum total output power, the input maximum power is Pout/eff=12.36/0.8=15.45. You can read the diodes' avg/rms current in LTspice waveform viewer by Ctrl+Click on the label of the waveform. If it exceeds, or comes too close to its specifications, it's too much. It's a good idea to stay below 50% of the datasheet. In your case, it seems safe, but you should also check the thermal dissipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LTSpice is telling you that a 13.5 volt peak amplitude sinewave has an RMS value of

$$\dfrac{13.5}{\sqrt2}$$

This is 9.5 volts RMS.

It's also telling you that the RMS current it supplies into the bridge is 1.96 amps but, the power delivered to the bridge and its output is only 12.36 watts.

This however doesn't mean that RMS current x RMS volts = watts. The bridge and reservoir capacitor is a highly non-linear circuit and the true power delivered is 12.36 watts but at a VA of 18.6 volt-amps.

Transformers are rated in VA and not watts.

Comment: Is there any way to obtain 18W from the transformer, maybe by putting an inductor/choke somewhere?

Comment: You can put an inductor in series with V1 feeding the bridge but it will have to be pretty big to get the form of power factor correction that you need. I'd highly consider buying a transformer with the appropriate ratings. I understand that may not be 1st priority to you but I'm just trying to save you time.

Comment: I did the simulations. Seems to be an inductor around 1mH to 10mH, that I can place before or just after the bridge. I'm wondering if it can be a tiny ferrite/iron powder toroid core (tiny 1.5cm dia), or does it have to be steel plates? Any chance of core saturation of the toroid inductor? I went to look for chokes today evening, but they seem to have become hard to find.

Comment: Saturation is always hanging around waiting to catch the unwary. You need to look at inductor specs and take into account what the peak current flowing will/might be. Ferrites saturate lower than laminated types.